# p:selectOneMenu doesn't set new value in bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'd like to use p:selectOneMenu as follows:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="actualCustomerSelect"  
    value="#{customer.currentCustomerUser}"
converter="userDisplayConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{customer.managers}" 
        var="manager"
        itemLabel="#{manager.userId}"
        itemValue="#{manager}"/>
    <p:ajax listener="#{customer.customerChangeListener}" partialSubmit="true"
            process="@this"></p:ajax>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

EDIT:

Now I'm using a helper class, that contains a User and an ArrayList of Users, if I set the ajax to immediate="true" then it calls the listener, otherwise not. (also doesn't set the new customer.currentCustomerUser)

Any idea how to get it work?

Thank you in advance!

---

The converter:

```
@FacesConverter("userDisplayConverter")
public class UserDisplayConverter extends AbsJsonConverter {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory
        .getLog(UserDisplayVOConverter.class);

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(Gson gson, FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String str) {


    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("getAsObject conversion of '" + str + "'");
    }

    return gson.fromJson(str, User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(Gson gson, FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object o) {

    User user = (User) o;

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("getAsString conversion of '" + user.getUserId() + "'");
    }

    String result = gson.toJson(user);

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Conversion result '" + result + "'");
    }

    return result;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

I think I'm one step closer to the problem:

In the ajax response I get validationFailed:true but I don't have a validator on anything :D

Comment: Please elaborate *"it fails"* in developer's perspective instead of enduser's.

Comment: post here code of `userDisplayConverter`

Comment: I think I'll use a list of a new helper class that contains the needed list and user. Maybe I had to start with this :D

Comment: The converter works perfectly, I'm using it in picklists

Comment: Edited the original question.